# Campo de una tabla en función de atributos de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, group-by

Tengo la tabla empleado:

```
CREATE TABLE empleado (
    nombreEmpleado VARCHAR(20),
    experiencia TINYINT(2),
    dni CHAR(10),
    emailEmpleado VARCHAR(45),
    telefono VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (dni)
);
```

Además tengo la tabla 'trabaja' que relaciona empleado con empresa:

```
CREATE TABLE trabaja(
    empresanombre VARCHAR(20),
    empleadodni CHAR(10),
    fechaIni DATE,
    fechaFin DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (empresanombre, empleadodni, fechaINI),
    FOREIGN KEY (empresanombre) REFERENCES empresa(nombre) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (empleadodni) REFERENCES empleado(dni) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Lo que intento hacer es que el campo experiencia de la tabla empleado (experiencia TINYINT2), sea calculado en función de los atributos fechaIni y FechaFin de la tabla trabaja. Habría que considerar que el empleado puede haber trabajado en varias empresas e incluso puede trabajar en la misma empresa en distintos periodos de tiempo. Entonces lo que que recoge el campo experiecia es la sumatoria total del tiempo trabajado por cada empleado.dni.

```
INSERT INTO empleado(nombreEmpleado, dni, emailEmpleado, telefono)
VALUES
    ('Amaya Petersen', '47959722-7', 'ap@ac.org', '1-886-355-2956'),
    ('Maris Tate', '41226301-4', 'mt@mail.org', '1-985-414-5782'),
    ('Fatima Estrada', '24532450-2', 'fe@eng.org', '1-214-797-0024'),
    ('Dante Hobbs', '30505973-0', 'db@mail.org', '1-107-744-9975')
```

```
INSERT INTO trabaja
VALUES
    ('IQ+LATAM', '47959722-7', '2008-08-10', '2011-04-30'),
    ('IQ+LATAM', '41226301-4', '2010-03-31', '2013-12-31'),
    ('IQ+LATAM', '24532450-2', '2005-05-10', '2012-02-28'),
    ('Capptan', '47959722-7', '2011-11-30', '2016-11-01'),
    ('Capptan', '41226301-4', '2014-04-10', '2016-04-30'),
    ('Develapps', '47959722-7', '2017-04-30', '2019-08-15')
```

Intentando conseguir lo anterior tengo este código:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fechaIni, fechaFin) AS años_transcurridos
FROM trabaja;
update empleado
set experiencia = años_transcurridos
where empleado.dni = trabaja.empleadodni;
```

Por lo visto si calcula los años trabajados, pero no los agrupa por empleado, ni me actualiza el campo experiencia en la tabla empleado.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, usas una tabla de muchos a muchos que por ser relacionada a tu tabla `empleado` y `empresa`, no es necesario colocar clave primaria para eso, ni mucho menos colocar una fecha como clave.

Segundo agregar la clave primaria como nombre de una empresa no está bien, ya que hay empresas que se llaman iguales, y por ende, al agregar un duplicado de empresa pero con otra razón social no podrás hacerlo en tu tabla, por eso es mejor un identificador como un `id` o un `rut` asociado, y mucho más ese tipo de relaciones. Lo que quedaría tu tabla de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE trabaja(
    empresaId INT,
    empleadodni CHAR(10),
    fechaIni DATE NOT NULL,
    fechaFin DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (empresaId) REFERENCES empresa(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (empleadodni) REFERENCES empleado(dni) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Tercero, la respuesta respuesta a tu problema es uso de `trigger`, lo que hace internamente es preguntar si después de hacer un `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`  de tu tabla `trabaja` realice una acción. Te dejo un ejemplo y un [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6D9iso6h5D8TPTcj9r6zxW/1) al momento de insertar:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER experiencia_en_anios AFTER INSERT ON trabaja
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @experiencia = (SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fechaIni, fechaFin)) FROM trabaja WHERE empleadodni = NEW.empleadodni);
        UPDATE empleado SET experiencia = @experiencia WHERE dni = NEW.empleadodni;
     END; 
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Cuarto. Este es un caso práctico, tu tarea es mejorar la consulta ya que al tener un empleado y sacar los años de experiencia con `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fechaIni, fechaFin)` varios meses entre rangos de fechas se pierden. Y para calcular los años exactos y tomar esos meses de descuento y sumarlos debes hacerlos de otra forma.

Y por último y no más importante, debes leerte la documentación de la sintaxis de MySQL: [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) por cualquier duda. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo corrí en db-fiddle y ciertamente funciona. Pero ejecuto este mismo codigo en MySQL Workbench y no actualiza el campo experiencia. Alguna idea de qué podrá ser?

Comment: Si seguiste los pasos, solo con correr el script ya debería funcionar. Y si ocupas workbench al hacer `Alter table` puedes buscar la pestaña `trigger` y crearlo desde ahí, haciendo un `add trigger` en `AFTER INSERT`